# difficulty to store the data in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, data-structures, plsql

I have a difficulty to store the data in the table. can you suggest me to store the data easily.

In below table 1 employee is working in different employee order per day, so that i am entering the working hours like below. For that every day i am altering table and adding column name like 09-JAN-12,10-JAN-12 to enter the working hours for each employee. Is there any other easy way to store the data in table in multiple table and query the records respectively.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
emp_name emp_order   05-Jan-12     06-Jan-1207-Jan-12
-----------------------------------------------------------
aaaaa    order11        3hours     5hours       6hours
aaaaa    order12        4hours     2hours       9hours
aaaaa    order13        8hours     3hours       7hours
ccccc    order11        3hours     5hours       6hours
ccccc    order12        4hours     2hours       9hours
ccccc    order13        8hours     3hours       7hours
bbbbb    order11        3hours     5hours       6hours
bbbbb    order12        4hours     2hours       9hours
bbbbb    order13        8hours     3hours       7hours
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

What i have tried: Instead of adding column i am entering data like below.. its also very hard to enter.

```
----------------------------------------------
emp_name    emp_order   working_Hours       date
----------------------------------------------
aaaaa       order11     5hours          05-JAN-12
aaaaa       order12     2hours          05-JAN-12
aaaaa       order13     3hours          05-JAN-12
ccccc       order11     5hours          05-JAN-12
ccccc       order12     2hours          05-JAN-12
ccccc       order13     3hours          05-JAN-12
bbbbb       order11     5hours          05-JAN-12
bbbbb       order12     2hours          05-JAN-12
bbbbb       order13     3hours          05-JAN-12

aaaaa       order11     6hours          06-JAN-12
aaaaa       order12     9hours          06-JAN-12
aaaaa       order13     7hours          06-JAN-12
ccccc       order11     6hours          06-JAN-12
ccccc       order12     9hours          06-JAN-12
ccccc       order13     7hours          06-JAN-12
bbbbb       order11     6hours          06-JAN-12
bbbbb       order12     9hours          06-JAN-12
bbbbb       order13     7hours          06-JAN-12

aaaaa       order11     7hours          07-JAN-12
aaaaa       order12     6hours          07-JAN-12
aaaaa       order13     3hours          07-JAN-12
ccccc       order11     7hours          07-JAN-12
ccccc       order12     6hours          07-JAN-12
ccccc       order13     3hours          07-JAN-12
bbbbb       order11     7hours          07-JAN-12
bbbbb       order12     6hours          07-JAN-12
bbbbb       order13     3hours          07-JAN-12

--------------------------------------------------
```

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: What does "very hard to enter" mean to you?  The second data model is the correct one (though I assume you aren't actually storing a string "5hours" but rather the number 5).  Data entry is a function of your front-end application.

Comment: Thank you cave, i mean, Is there any other good way to store the working_hours and date in different table,Unnecessarily I am entring the emp_name, emp_order details once again.

Comment: Do you think any other data model will be good to store the records?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have an `employee` table or an `order` table?  I would assume that you'd have both of those tables and that `emp_name` and `emp_order` are foreign keys that point to the appropriate row in the parent tables.

Comment: Your second model is correct. If it is difficult to enter multiple line of same data for every employee everyday you may consider stored procedure. Or create application for each employee to record their working hours

Answer (score 0):

create a view of the table with only columns emp_name,emp_order and then based on the view you created try to make in your front-end emp_name and emp_order as a drop down list .Then in the front-end just enter the working hours and Date(you can make the date also default based on trunc(sysdate) )

Comment: UI part is fine...Is Storing the data in second model is Fine? I thought of if we split this table and it should be fine. You mean Am i right on second data model?

Comment: The second model is right ,if you create a view you can save having redundant data

Answer (score 0):

your second model is so better and you can use this query on it:

```
select 
emp_name,
emp_order,
rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement(e,Date||'('||working_Hours||'Hours), ')).extract ('//text()'), ', ') as Final_Date
from 
Table1
where 
group by emp_name,emp_order;
```

Comment: I didn't get you what you are saying... Can you explain.

Comment: it is so simple you can create a table with this columns:emp_name,emp_order,working_Hours,date and you can see your first table results whith my query